# Plugin functionality should not work in wordpress in admin dasboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I am asking a question, which might be quite tricky to solve. I have a custom wordpress plugin, which displays widjet in left side of the front end.

But my question is that when i load into wordpress admin dashboard,it working in wordpress admin pannel also. How can i stop working the same

Following is my code in functions.php of plugin

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'sm1waze_define' );
function sm1waze_define()
{
    if(!defined('SM1WAZE_BASE_DIR'))
    {
        define( 'SM1WAZE_BASE_DIR', plugin_basename(__FILE__));
    }

    if(!defined('SM1WAZE_VIEWS_DIR'))
    {
        define( 'SM1WAZE_VIEWS_DIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'views/' );
    }

    if(!defined('SM1WAZE_ASSETS_DIR'))
    {
        define( 'SM1WAZE_ASSETS_DIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'assets/' );
    }

    if(!defined('SM1WAZE_ASSETS'))
    {
        define( 'SM1WAZE_ASSETS', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/' );
    }

    if(!defined('SM1WAZE_SRC'))
    {
        define( 'SM1WAZE_SRC', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'src/' );
    }
}

/*
* Register Smart1Waze Classes
*/
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'sm1waze_load' );
function sm1waze_load()
{
    if(is_admin())
    {
        new Smart1Waze_Widget_Frontend();
    }
    else
    {

        new Smart1Waze_Widget_Frontend();
    }
}

/* 
* Auto Load Smart1Waze Classes & Include Class Files
*/
spl_autoload_register('sm1waze_autoload');
function sm1waze_autoload($class)
{   
    if (0 === strpos( $class, 'Smart1Waze_Widget_' ) )
    {
        $path = SM1WAZE_SRC.$class.'.php';
    }

    if ( isset($path) && is_readable( $path ) )
    {
        require_once($path);
    }
}
```

In this code am checking with `is_admin`

What is the problem here?

Comment: `is_admin()` indicates wp admin dashboard page. To detect whether  user is admin you'd use smth like  `current_user_can('manage_options')`

Comment: My problem is only that, widjet is not showing in admin dashboard, but its works perfectly in frontend

Comment: apparently wp admin page may have some kind of template, but does this template really have any widget call area?

Comment: `add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'sm1waze_load' );`

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: try to add this line

Comment: I have added and still its not working, i mean widjet is still not showing in admin pannel